# Floating social icons above footer

Tags: jquery, html, css

I need some guidance on how to best approach an issue when it comes to fixed div elements of a web page.

**ISSUE:**
Full-width horizontal fixed social icons are visible at the bottom of a mobile screen and travel with you as a user scrolls the page. As a user scrolls and reaches the end of the web page, the social icons as overlapping the footer area.

**DESIRED GOAL:**
The desired outcome is to have the full-width horizontal fixed social icons visible at the bottom of the web page, however, would like the icons to stop before the footer and not overlap it.

Example:

[image]

How should I approach this as what seems to be a common problem? Thank you :)

Comment: Why not add `padding-bottom` to your main div that is the same as the height of the fixed element?  Then the page will scroll until the footer is visible above the social buttons.

Comment: Try it. As it is a fixed element `padding-bottom` has no effect. I can only position  via `top` `bottom` `left` `right`

Comment: can you post the html and css that you have tried?

Comment: I've uploaded a wireframe image that would provide more clarity of the desired outcome.

Answer (score 0):

If you add `padding-bottom` to the footer equal to the height of the fixed element, the footer will scroll into view above the fixed div.  This is the opposite order to what the OP proposed, but is the simplest solution:

```css
#container {
  height: 1000px;
  width: 100px;
  background: silver;
  position: relative;
}
#footer {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  background: black;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
#fixed {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="footer"></div>
</div>
<div id="fixed"></div>
```

Comment: thanks for helping out so far. Still not quite what I'm looking for. However, I've uploaded a wireframe image that would provide more clarity of the desired outcome.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<footer>` from html and edit the margin-top: 30px; with css. That way the footer will not overlap with div, video etc :)
You can also use hr inside the footer and it will look even nicer

```
<footer> <hr> &copy; this is footer <footer>
```

Comment: I've uploaded a wireframe image that would provided more clarity of the desired outcome.